# VBA cut string between two slash

Tags: excel, vba

I'm VBA nwebie. I would like to cut String between two slash. This is my String

```
    /branches/test
```

and I would like to get the following output

```
     branches
```

how should I define it?

Comment: what happens to `test`? btw, you can use `Spit` function to get the strings. see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) for examples on how to use the function.

Comment: @L42: Yes, that will `Spit` out the right result :-)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett haha sorry, my bad. it should be `Split`. I provided a link though to help the OP somehow. :D

Comment: In one go... `Debug.print Split("/branches/test","/")(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I need

```
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    x = Split("/branches/test", "/")
    For i = 1 To UBound(x)
        Debug.Print x(i)
    Next i
```

The out put is

```
      branches
      test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed by the `Split` Function;

```
Dim s as string = "/branches/test"
Dim sArray() As String
Dim result As String

sArray = Split(s, "/") 
result = sArray(1)
```

Comment: You should test before you post. (`sArray(1)` returns the `branches`.  element `0` is up to the first delimiter, in this case an empty string)

Comment: Ok, edited, thanks. I don't have environment to test at the moment.